# Remove -webkit transform/transform class with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, webkit, removeclass

I'm trying to create an expanding column layout: when you hover over the pictures it blurs and zooms and when you click on it it expands.

I'm trying to remove the blur and zoom effect once the image has expanded.

I've tried removeProp() and document.getElementById('').style.setProperty("webkit-filter", "none") but neither of them worked.

Any insights or tips would be greatly appreciated!!!

Thank you :)

Here's my JS:

```js
var Expand = (function() {
  var tile = $('.photo');
  var tileLink = $('.photo > .photo-content');
  var tileText = tileLink.find('.photo-inner-text');
  var stripClose = $('.photo-close');
  var tileAnimate = ('.photo:hover');

  var expanded  = false;

  var open = function() {

    var tile = $(this).parent();

      if (!expanded) {
        tile.addClass('photo__expanded');
        // add delay to inner text
        tileText.css('transition', 'all .6s 1s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1)');
        stripClose.addClass('photo-close__show');
        stripClose.css('transition', 'all .6s 1s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1)');
        tileAnimate.removeProp('filter', '-webkit-filter');
        expanded = true;
      }
    };

  var close = function() {
    if (expanded) {
      tile.removeClass('photo__expanded');
      // remove delay from inner text
      tileText.css('transition', 'all 0.15s 0 cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1)');
      stripClose.removeClass('photo-close__show');
      stripClose.css('transition', 'all 0.2s 0s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1)')
      expanded = false;
    }
  }

    var bindActions = function() {
      tileLink.on('click', open);
      stripClose.on('click', close);
    };

    var init = function() {
      bindActions();
    };

    return {
      init: init
    };

  }());

Expand.init();
```

My CSS (a little messy, I apologize):

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald);

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #000;
}

div {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


.main-container {
  min-height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: white;
}


.photo {
  background-color: #0c2d50;
  will-change: width, left, z-index, height;
  position: absolute;
  width: 20%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 1s;
}

.photo:nth-child(1) {
  left: 0;
  background: url("../images/image1.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}
.photo:nth-child(2) {
  left: 20vw;
  background: url("../images/image2.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}
.photo:nth-child(3) {
  left: 40vw;
  background: url("../images/image3.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}
.photo:nth-child(4) {
  left: 60vw;
  background: url("../images/image4.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}
.photo:nth-child(5) {
  left: 80vw;
  background: url("../images/image1.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}

.photo:active,
.photo:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
  -webkit-transform:scale(1.15); /* Safari and Chrome */
  -moz-transform:scale(1.15); /* Firefox */
  -ms-transform:scale(1.15); /* IE 9 */
  -o-transform:scale(1.15); /* Opera */
   transform:scale(1.15);
}

.photo {
  background-color: #000;
  height: 100vh;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease; /* Firefox */
  -o-transition: all .5s ease; /* IE 9 */
  -ms-transition: all .5s ease; /* Opera */
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

.photo:nth-child(1) .photo-content {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  -webkit-animation-name: photo1;
          animation-name: photo1;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.1s;
          animation-delay: 0.1s;
}
.photo:nth-child(2) .photo-content {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  -webkit-animation-name: photo2;
          animation-name: photo2;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s;
          animation-delay: 0.2s;
}
.photo:nth-child(3) .photo-content {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  -webkit-animation-name: photo3;
          animation-name: photo3;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s;
          animation-delay: 0.3s;
}
.photo:nth-child(4) .photo-content {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  -webkit-animation-name: photo4;
          animation-name: photo4;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.4s;
          animation-delay: 0.4s;
}
.photo:nth-child(5) .photo-content {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  -webkit-animation-name: photo5;
          animation-name: photo5;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
          animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

/*******************************************************
.photo  a:active img,
.photo a:hover img {
  opacity: .6;
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
  -webkit-transform:scale(1.15); /* Safari and Chrome
  -moz-transform:scale(1.15); /* Firefox
  -ms-transform:scale(1.15); /* IE 9
  -o-transform:scale(1.15); /* Opera
   transform:scale(1.15);
}

.photo img {
  height: 100vh;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease; /* Safari and Chrome
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease; /* Firefox
  -o-transition: all .5s ease; /* IE 9
  -ms-transition: all .5s ease; /* Opera
  transition: all .5s ease;
}
****************************************************/

.photo-content {
  position:relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* text hidden */
.photo-title {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Oswald';
  font-size: 4em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease; /* Firefox */
  -o-transition: all .5s ease; /* IE 9 */
  -ms-transition: all .5s ease; /* Opera */
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

/* text shown on hover */
.photo a:active .photo-title,
.photo a:hover .photo-title {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-animation: flicker 2s infinite; /* Flicker effect */
  -webkit-transition: all 1.5s ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
  -moz-transition: all 1.5s ease; /* Firefox */
  -o-transition: all 1.5s ease; /* IE 9 */
  -ms-transition: all 1.5s ease; /* Opera */
  transition: all 1.5s ease;
}

@-webkit-keyframes flicker {
  0% {opacity:0;}
  9% {opacity:0;}
  10% {opacity:.5;}
  13% {opacity:0;}
  20% {opacity:.5;}
  25% {opacity:1;}
}

/* added for slider */
.main-container .photo-content {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
          animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
          animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
          animation-fill-mode: both;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.main-container .photo-content:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
  opacity: 0.05;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
      -ms-transform-origin: center center;
          transform-origin: center center;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
          transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
}
.main-container .photo-inner-text {
  will-change: transform, opacity;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 70%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.5);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.5);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.5);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
          transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
}

.photo__expanded {
  width: 100%;
  top: 0 !important;
  left: 0 !important;
  z-index: 3;
  cursor: default;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.photo__expanded .photo-title {
  opacity: 0;
}

.photo__expanded .photo-inner-text {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
}

.photo-close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 3vw;
  top: 3vw;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
          transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.5s;
          transition-delay: 0.5s;
}
.photo-close__show {
  opacity: 1;
}

@-webkit-keyframes photo1 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes photo1 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes photo2 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}
@keyframes photo2 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes photo3 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}
@keyframes photo3 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes photo4 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}
@keyframes photo4 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes photo5 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}
@keyframes photo5 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}


.fa {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
}
```

And my HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Abtin Animation</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootloader.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <section class="main-container">

        <article class="photo">
          <div class="photo-content">
            <div class="photo-title">LAUGH</div>
          </div>
        </article>

        <article class="photo">
            <div class="photo-content">
              <div class="photo-title">DREAM</div>
              <div class="photo-inner-text"><h1>hey</h1><p>testing</p></div>
            </div>
        </article>

        <article class="photo">
            <div class="photo-content">
              <div class="photo-title">LIVE</div>
            </div>
        </article>

        <article class="photo">
            <div class="photo-content">
              <div class="photo-title">PLAY</div>
            </div>
        </article>

        <article class="photo">
          <div class="photo-content">
            <div class="photo-title">LAUGH</div>
          </div>
        </article>

        <i class="fa fa-close photo-close"></i>
    </section>
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Does `tileAnimate.css('-webkit-filter', 'none')` not work?

Comment: Nope :( just tried it